# Что лучше использовать HTTP-заголовки или meta-тэги?

Tags: php, html

Например `Content-Type` или `Cache-Control`? Мне кажется, что нужно отдавать приоритет meta-тэгам.

Answer (score 2):

Корректнее всего для HTML использовать и заголовки, и метатеги.

---

- **Заголовки** – часть стандартизированного HTTP-протокола.
  Их нужно использовать **обязательно**, если вы общаетесь с сервером посредством HTTP.
  Не стоит полагаться на наличие у пользователя умного браузера.
- **meta**-теги нужны (в основном) тогда, когда сценарий предполагает отсутствие HTTP-сервера.
  Например, когда мы сохраняем страницу и позже открываем её локально. В файле нет заголовков, поэтому такие вещи как кодировка следует добавить в метатеги.

Не нужно забывать также и то, что взаимодействие с веб-сервером не ограничивается **mime=text/html**. Заголовки пригодятся во всех остальных случаях(text/plain, application/json и тд), а соответствующих "метатегов" в разных форматах может и не быть.

Comment: Но всё же чему следует отдавать приоритет? Тегам или заголовкам? По идее теги нагляднее и к тому же мы убираем вызов функции header() на php.

Comment: @Khipster Отдавайте заголовкам. Это приказ.

Comment: @Rou1997 А если серьёзно?

Comment: @Khipster, это и было серьёзно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хватит шутить. Ответьте серьёзно.

Comment: @Khipster А если серьезно - что лучше, пицца или роллы? Что из этого кушать, а что необходимо забыть как страшный сон?

Comment: @Rou1997 Ты ошибся, умник.